# Typescript error :TS2304 cannot find name

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Burning through a typescript course I came across these code pieces that fail to compile and give error TS2304. Any help is appreciated.

file ZooAnimals.ts:

```
namespace Zoo {
    interface Animal {
        skinType: string;
        isMammal(): boolean;
    }
}
```

File ZooBirds.ts:

```
/// <reference path="ZooAnimals.ts" />
namespace Zoo {
    export class Bird implements Animal {
        skinType = "feather";
        isMammal() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The command to compile the files:

```
tsc --outFile Zoo.js ZooAnimals.ts ZooBirds.ts
```

Throws error:

```
ZooBirds.ts:3:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Animal'.

3     export class Bird implements Animal {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the interface across files (or more precisely across multiple `namespace` declarations) it must be exported (even if it is part of the same namespace). This will work:

```
namespace Zoo {
    export interface Animal {
        skinType: string;
        isMammal(): boolean;
    }
}
namespace Zoo {
    export class Bird implements Animal {
        skinType = "feather";
        isMammal() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That certainly works - thanks. The edX course (from Microsoft) suggests to use '/// <reference path='...' /> ' tag to resolve the inclusion of the Animal definition and not export the interface. But somehow the reference path does not seem to be working. Wondering if I am doing something wrong or the version of typescript that can only work as suggested by you.

Comment: @rks The `<reference...>` might still be needed for the definitions to be discovered. But the `export` is most definitely required..

Comment: Actually it works without needing the `<reference .../>` tag if the interface is exported.
Here is the code from the course:

ZooAnimals.ts
`namespace Zoo { 
    interface Animal { //note that we do not need the *export* here since this interface will only be accessible only by entities from within the Zoo namespace
   skinType: string;
        isMammal(): boolean;
    }
}`

Comment: @rks it should work without the `///<ref` as well if all the files are included in the compilation .. it was probably an oversight in the course..